# conditional if / else

Tags: conditionals

I want in following examaple change the day of week according the inputted day. When I use dia in the document work, but when I use inside newcommand doesnt (look the example)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\makeatletter
\def\dia#1{\ifstrequal{#1}{monday}{thuesday}{something}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\dayone}{monday}
\newcommand{\daytwo}{\dia{\dayone}}
\def\daytwo{\dia{\dayone}}
\begin{document}

If variable dayone is monday the resul must be thuesday, and is \daytwo \\

But if I use dia the result is correct.\\

\dia{monday}\\

\dia{asdasd}\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: unrelated to the question but never do `But if I use dia the result is correct.\\ ` you get poor output and tex warns about underfull hbox with maximum (10000) measure of badness.

Comment: I write this for help to understand

Comment: Just so others can make the link more quickly a link to your related earlier question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/430029/35864

Comment: Your problem here is that in the context of `\ifstrequal` the string `monday` and the macro `\dayone` which expands to `monday` are two different things. So "`\dayone`!=monday". What you need to do here is to unpack (in TeX lingo: expand) the definition before you compare the string.

Comment: Maybe consider to accept helpful answers. You have some questions with answers.